# How to add a text above half arrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-{Straight Barb[left]}] (0,0)--(0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! How about `\draw [-{Straight Barb[left]}] (0,0)--(0.5,0)node[midway,above]{text};`? Or `\draw [-{Straight Barb[left]}] (0,0)--node[above]{text}(0.5,0);`?

Comment: It will add text with a circle node. But I need text without circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520332/how-to-add-a-text-above-half-arrows/520334#comment1315938_520332): [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520332/how-to-add-a-text-above-half-arrows/520334#comment1315937_520332) were my suggestions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-{Straight Barb[left]}] (0,0)--node[above]{text}(0.5,0);
\draw [-{Straight Barb[left]}] (3,0)--(3.5,0) node[midway,above]{text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

IMHO there is no circle node (but there may be a misinterpretation).

As for your [comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520332/how-to-add-a-text-above-half-arrows/520334?noredirect=1#comment1315950_520334): you have

```
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
```

which instructs every node to be drawn and to have circle shape. (This syntax is deprecated, you should use `\tikzset{node={draw,shape=circle}}` instead.) In order not to draw the circle and to have standard rectangle shaped nodes, use

```
\draw [-{Latex[left]}]
(v0.10)--(v4.170)node[midway,above,shape=rectangle,draw=none]{text};
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw,shape=circle}] 
\node (v0) at (0:0) {c};
\node (v1) at (90:2) {...};
\node (v2) at (90+1*90:2) {1}; 
\node (v3) at (90+2*90:2) {o};
\node (v4) at (90+3*90:2) {$n$};
\draw [-{Latex[left]}] (v0.100) -- (v1.260);
\draw [-{Latex[left]}] (v1.280)--(v0.80);
\draw [-{Latex[left]}] (v2.10)-- (v0.170);
\draw [-{Latex[left]}]
(v0.10)--(v4.170)node[midway,above,shape=rectangle,draw=none]{text};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had this line : \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]. Could this be a reason?

Comment: @user148342 I am sorry, I am not sure I understand what that means.

Comment: \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
\node (v0) at (0:0) {c};\node (v1) at (90:2) {...};\node (v2) at (90+1*90:2) {1};
\node (v3) at (90+2*90:2) {o};\node (v4) at (90+3*90:2) {$n$};\draw [-{Latex[left]}] (v0.100) -- (v1.260);\draw [-{Latex[left]}] (v1.280)--(v0.80);\draw [-{Latex[left]}] (v2.10)-- (v0.170);\draw [-{Latex[left]}] (v0.10)--(v4.170)node[midway,above]{text};\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: I have this type of figure, where I have parallel half arrows. I need to put text above or below each arrow.

Comment: @user148342 There is a circle because you have `\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];`. Please have a look at the update of my answer.

Comment: This helps a lot! Thank you! Do you know how to change the font size of the text?

Comment: @user148342 Yes, use `font`, e.g. `\draw [-{Latex[left]}]
(v0.10)--(v4.170)node[midway,above,shape=rectangle,draw=none,font=\small]{text};`.

Comment: For arrows which are down, how to put a text so it is also rotated like 90 degrees?

Comment: @user148342 Add the `sloped` key, e.g. `... node[midway,above,shape=rectangle,draw=none,font=\small,sloped]{text};`.

Comment: Do I still need to have "above" key with "sloped" key? Because it is not compiling.

Comment: @user148342 In general, yes. Sometimes you need to add the `allow upside down` key.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!